# EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/app/yarn-error.log' in Windows

Tags: docker, node-modules, yarnpkg

So I was going through the docker tutorial and I executed this in my power shell:

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 `
-w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" `
node:12-alpine `
sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

But my container exited immediately after running.
So after observing the logs, this seems to be the problem:

```
yarn install v1.22.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error Could not write file "/app/yarn-error.log": "EPERM: operation not permitted, open 
'/app/yarn-error.log'"
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/app/node_modules'".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I ran the PowerShell in admin mode, no project files are read-only and in folder properties, user and admin have full control. So why is the problem occurring?

Comment: Could you download [Node](https://nodejs.org/) and use that directly, instead of trying to route your workflow through Docker?

Comment: Of course, but this is just an example, I need to learn how to do this in order to replicate this process.

Comment: It is a drag but Windows just has too many issues (like viruses, permissions) that can mess with docker containers. My advice to new comers is just don't use Windows if you can help it.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by changing the folder right access /app/.
It only allowed me to make changes so I change it to allow the access write execute and read to all and it worked, just fine.

So changing the right access of your folder should solved your issue.

Comment: "There is probably a better way to do it" is not an answer. Consider updating your answer with something better that is actually helpful.